# jquery ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my jquery code for ajax :

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("IsLoggedIn","Ajax")',
            type: "POST",
            data: "Command=CheckLogin",
            cache:false,
            success: function (dataFromServer) {
                if ($.trim(dataFromServer) == "no") {
                    showLoginAndRegisterNowForm(obj);
                }
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert(c);
            }
        });
```

This code wrote in separated .js file and add to .cshtml page with  tag.
My Controller name in `Controllers` folder is `AjaxController.cs` and it's different from this page Controller.
Controller method is :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult IsLoggedIn(string Command)
        {
            return Content("yes");
        }
```

When i use this code, ajax goes to `error` function and said `internal server error`.
What should i do?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside "IsLoggedIn" and see what happens when after it's hit.

Comment: With your javascript in a separate file the `@Url.Action("IsLoggedIn", "Ajax")` will not produce the url string you are expecting.

Comment: Simplify your life...  Use JSON instead of HTML.  Change to `public ActionResult IsLoggedIn...` and `return Json(new { status = "success" });`

Comment: @Jasen so what should i do if i want my js file keep separate?

Comment: @user1477388 Could you make an answer more clear?Thanks ...

Comment: @samangholami you'll need to write out the url manually e.g. `/Ajax/IsLoggedIn` or write it out in your view page `<input type="hidden" val=@Url.Action("IsLoggedIn", "Ajax") id="url" />` then in your javascript `var url = $("#url").val()`

Comment: @samangholami Look here for an example http://robvolk.com/using-jquery-to-read-json-returned-from-an-mvc-controller-method/

Comment: @samangholami Look here for a more complex example http://www.akhildeshpande.com/2011/08/simple-jquery-getjson-example-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Url,**in separated js file** to `url: "/Ajax/IsLoggedIn"` solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to programatically generate URLs based on your MVC routes, consider giving your script an initialization function where you pass in configuration, like URLs. Then initialize your script in your Razor view with an inline script block:

```
<script>
    yourJSModule.initialize({
        isLoggedInUrl: '@Url.Action("IsLoggedIn","Ajax")'
    });
</script>
```

This way, you keep the benefit of non-hard-coded URLs and of separate script files (excepting your initialization).

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved the problem, but I sent you because maibe it is useful. Also it is usefull when you have set virtualpath. With this example, you don't need javascript in your page (cshtml).

CSHTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="UrlAjaxIsLoggedIn" value="@Url.Action("IsLoggedIn","Ajax")" />
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#UrlAjaxIsLoggedIn').val(),
    type: "POST",
    data: "Command=CheckLogin",
    cache: false,
    success: function (dataFromServer) {
        if ($.trim(dataFromServer) == "no") {
            showLoginAndRegisterNowForm(obj);
        }
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        alert(c);
    }
});
```